# hcitool lescan (Bluetooth LE) in docker under Non-Privileged & Non-host Network mode is possible?

Tags: bluetooth, docker, bluez

I am a newbie to docker. For a specific task, I am failing to scan BLE/BlueZ in docker under Non-Privileged and Non-Host network mode. These are my results in Debian-Jessie-8.8.0 Host and debian:jessie docker image):

```
root1@73ab53a9268e:/# hciconfig -a
Can't open HCI socket.: Operation not permitted
root1@73ab53a9268e:/# bt-device -l
Couldn't connect to DBus system bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
root2@0d208802d44a:/# hciconfig -a
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I even gave ALL-CAP permissions for docker on Host but still could not make it.

```
docker run --name container-ID --cap-add=ALL -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock -v /dev:/host/dev -v /proc:/host/proc:ro -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro -v /usr:/host/usr:ro Image-ID
```

So, is it possible by any chance to scan BLE/BlueZ in docker under Non-Privileged and Non-Host network mode?

Answer (score 2):

Almost Done...!

With help from Docker Community, **First I have Successfully Started DBus Service** inside docker container by logging in docker as follows :

`docker run -v /opt/bluetooth:/var/lib/bluetooth -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -v /tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run -it debian:jessie`

Then by adding **--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN** and **--net=host** this permission, Possible to start bluetooth service.

`docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v /opt/bluetooth:/var/lib/bluetooth -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -v /tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run --net=host -it debian:jessie`

Now just looking to start bluetooth service by "Not sharing the Host Networking Namespace"  (customising --net=host to private network)

If somebody got any Clue, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded half:

With help from the Docker community, I have successfully started the DBus Service inside docker container by logging in docker as follows:

```
docker run -v /opt/bluetooth:/var/lib/bluetooth -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
  -v /tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run -it debian:jessie
```

Just looking to start the Bluetooth service next... if somebody got any clue, that would be helpful.